# What was Garuda's previous life?

Tags: garuda

As we know, *Garuda* known as god of birds' character comes in purana as son of *Vinata* to free his mother from slavery from *Kadru*.

But

- Is there any book says regarding the previous life of Garuda?
- What made him to take birth from Vinata?
- What he has done in his previous life so that he became the vehicle mount (vahana) of Lord Vishnu?

Comment: Garuda is a deity himself. He is praised as early as the Rigveda as Garutman.

Comment: According to madhva taratamya 5th level in taratamya tree is Garuda, Sesha and Rudra.  To attain rudra status jiva have 10kalpa tapas underwater another 30 Kalpa in land similarly twice as much for sesha and twice that of sesha is Garuda  so Garuda was sesha in his previous birth